# YADCF Plugin - Get Date Function From Eonasdan Bootstrap Datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, datatables, yadcf

How to get the dates from yadcf plugin date range?

Because i want to get the dates and include it when saving my records to pdf

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [exGetColumnFilterVal](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/blob/5dc8b18ffbe4f37eaf2cdb57feed859abfc99350/src/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js#L325) for that purpose

```
* exGetColumnFilterVal
            Description:        Allows to retrieve  column current filtered value (support ALL filter types!!!)
            Arguments:          table_arg: (variable of the datatable),
                                column number:  column number from which we want the value
            Usage example:      yadcf.exGetColumnFilterVal(oTable,1);
            Return value:       String (for simple filter) / Object (for range filter) with from and to properties / Array of strings for multi_select filter
```